# How to change background color of storyboard in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm working with white text (labels) in Xcode, and currently I can't see them because the background of the storyboard is also white. How do I change the appearance of the storyboard?

To clarify, I do not want my text to change color, I only want to change the appearance of the storyboard so that I can develop more easily.

Comment: Do you mean the background of the viewcontroller? You can set this using the inspector.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are referring to the white in your view controller:

- Select the View
- Go to inspector (right panel, 4th item)
- Change the background color field (section view)

Comment: I cannot change since the view panel cannot show everything. What is going on actually?

Comment: Well that changes the actual view's colour so that will appear on-device as well. Is there no way to change the XCode background?

Comment: To show the panel on the right, click the square icon in the top right corner of xcode (the icon has a little square with inside a vertical line on the right side.)
Then, switch to the Attributes Inspector by selecting the fourth icon (the one that looks like the "V" widget from a slider.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do what you're trying to achieve. My best advice to you would be to create a dark coloured `UIView` which you can place behind the `UILabel`. Once you're happy you've got the `UILabel` setup the way you want it you can then just delete the `UIView`.